# Console progress percentage not increasing as expected

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to show the percentage complete in the console:

```
Console.Clear();
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
Console.Write("Progress: ");
Console.Write(int_current);
Console.Write(" of ");
Console.Write(int_total);
Console.Write(" ( ");
Console.Write((int_current / int_total) * 100);
Console.Write(" %) ");
```

As the code runs, I can see the `int_current` increasing as expected, but the `(int_current / int_total) * 100` remains at `0%` until `int_current` and `int_total` are the same value.  At that point, it shows `100%`.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Use `((double)int_current / int_total) * 100`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a type converter. When divided by int_total it always returns 0 integer part and returns 0.

```
            var int_current = 30;
            var int_total = 100;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            Console.Write("Progress: ");
            Console.Write(int_current);
            Console.Write(" of ");
            Console.Write(int_total);
            Console.Write(" ( ");
            Console.Write(Math.Round(((float)int_current / int_total) * 100));
            Console.Write(" %) ");
```